# How do I await the result of EvaluateJavascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a CustomWebViewRenderer for Android that contains an event to process javascript using EvaluateJavascript, and I have a Callback object to catch the result of the javascript, but I need to send that result back up the chain to the initial calling function. Right now OnRunJavascript completes before OnRecieveValue runs, so e.Result is not set properly.

```
public void OnRunJavascript(object sender, JavascriptEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control != null)
    {
            var jsr = new JavascriptResult();
            Control.EvaluateJavascript(string.Format("javascript: {0}", e.Script), jsr);
            e.Result = jsr.Result;
     }
}


            public class JavascriptResult : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
            {
                public string Result;
                public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object result)
                {
                    string json = ((Java.Lang.String)result).ToString();
                    Result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
                    Notify();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a TaskCompletionSource with async/await.  I like this because it's simple (relatively little code), and let's me quickly turn synchronous code into something that looks like async code.

Using your example, I will add in a TaskCompletionSource and create a Task which can be used with await later on in your program.

```
public void OnRunJavascript(object sender, JavascriptEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control != null)
    {
        var jsr = new JavascriptResult();
        Control.EvaluateJavascript(string.Format("javascript: {0}", e.Script), jsr);
        // TODO await jsr.CompletionTask
        e.Result = jsr.Result;
     }
}


public class JavascriptResult : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
{
    public string Result;

    public Task CompletionTask {get { return jsCompletionSource.Task; } }

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> jsCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        string json = ((Java.Lang.String)result).ToString();
        Result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
        Notify();
        jsCompletionSource.SetResult(true); // completes the Task
        // the await will finish
    }
}
```

Notice the TODO inside OnRunJavascript which, I believe, is what you're looking to accomplish.  That Task can be passed somewhere else to be awaited and then access the JavascriptResult.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but what is A TODO?

Comment: Don't worry about that at all.  :)  A TODO just indicates that there is some work left to be done before the code works.  It's something left for the reader "to do".